# How to separate different objects appearing on the same line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, content-type

So I created an array of objects that contain some data like name, id, etc.... I used the res.json() method to transform the array of objects into json data so that my browser would be able to use it. The problem is that I typed the array of object data like this:

```
[
  {

    id: 1,
    name: 'albany sofa', 
    image:   'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/6ac7f7b55d505
    price: 39.95,
    desc: `I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian.`,
  }, 

  {

    id: 2,
    name: 'entertainment center',
    image:'https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/
    price: 29.98,
    desc: `I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian.`,
  },
]
```

Whenever I launch my server, the data comes out like this:

```
`[{"id":1,"name":"albanysofa","image":"https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/6ac7f7b55d505057317534722e5a9f03/9183491e/product-3.jpg","price":39.95,"desc":"I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian."},{"id":2,"name":"entertainmentcenter","image":"https://dl.airtable.com/.attachments/da5e17fd71f50578d525dd5f596e407e/d5e88ac8/product-2.jpg","price":29.98,"desc":"I'm baby direct trade farm-to-table hell of, YOLO readymade raw denim venmo whatever organic gluten-free kitsch schlitz irony af flexitarian."}`
```

Meaning that it appears on one line. Meanwhile when I typed it out, I organized it. How do I fix it? Is this not as big an issue as I am seeing it? Also, when I checked for the content-type in the browser, it was missing.

Comment: Not a problem. Looks like he resulting JSON has been minified to reduce the size of it. It still represents the same structure just without any unnecessary white space.

Comment: ah thanks. what of the fact that when i click inspect on my browser, i see that the content-type that is meant to be showing 'application/json' is missing?

Comment: A well behaved server should really include that, but it usually won't affect things if you're expecting JSON. It becomes a problem when an application say it will accept different content-types in the response and the application is free to choose which it responds with.

Answer (score 0):

Addidional spaces and new lines are ignored inside JSON. So the JSON data you have posted is perfectly valid and will be parsed normal by any fuction that requires a JSON parameter. Many API testing tools support JSON beautify ex. in Postman by default, JSON is represented "Pretty".

[image]

If for readability or other reasons you'd want to view your JSON like that, you can use 3rd party [JSON beautifier tools](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

Comment: damn thanks. I thought i was doing it wrong. Is there any way to make it appear normal straight from my vscode or node server

Comment: VSCode uses system default terminal as console. If I am not mistaken by default cmd, powershell (or any MacOS terminal apps) does not support json formatting. None of json related extensions I've tested works on terminal level. In other words output comes directly from terminal app VSCode chooses to run. That said I am not sure if there is any way to change powershell or cmd to treat json output specially.

Comment: ah thanks.   what of the fact that when i click inspect on my browser, i see that the content-type that is meant to be showing 'application/json' is missing?

Comment: I guess should add "Content-Type" header key if it does not appear automatically. the way of adding headers changes depending which framework u use. Ex. I use FastAPI and Django and both of them automatically adds application/json value to the key